# BJT as a switch: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm studying the following circuit
[image]

The image is explicit but as you can see the input measured in the upper terminal is a square wave with \$E_c\$ and \$-E_c\$ as levels.

Now I also had no trouble understanding that if \$R_B \leq \beta R_C\$ when the square wave is in the positive half-cycle we have saturation and when it is on the negative half-cycle we have cutoff situation.

Now in saturation we will (because the junction voltages are zero) an output voltage of zero. That is correct with the figure. However when we are in cutoff, applying KVL to the output mesh leads us to

$$U_{CE}=-E_c$$

because currents can be neglected. 
That however is not concordant with the figure which shows $$U_{CE}=E_c$$
Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: That is NOT how you use a BJT as a switch. Try "bjt switch" in google and search for images. You will find a few hundred circuits which all have in common that the collector is connected,through a resistor, to a STATIC supply.

Comment: Where do that circuit (and the 2 time diagrams) come from? I think they’re just plain wrong.